# How to fix low quality decision tree visualisation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm trying to visulise a decision tree i've just constructed, however the figure is always low quality and you can't read the labels! Just wondering if there is a fix for this?

My code for brining up the graph is below, I can't zoom in using the figure viewer either.

```
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
plt.figure()
plot_tree(model, filled=True)
plt.title("Decision tree")
plt.savefig('testfig.svg', format='svg', dpi=1200)
plt.show()
```

The model is a standard decison tree classifer as shown below.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=20)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I've tried messing with the dpi and file type, as well as saving directly from the figure viewer but nothing has worked, I just need it so that I can export it and see the labels.

Comment: Two questions: (1) How many nodes are in the tree / how big are they? (2) Are you comfortable with graphviz?

Comment: I’m moderately comfortable with graphviz and I believe it’s about 40 nodes

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue. Is it possible that you're on a system where matplotlib does not handle `.svg` correctly? I've added an answer comparing svg outputs and a graphviz output.

Comment: For example: if you're in a Jupyter notebook, or a "scientific IDE prompt" like Spyder/VSCode/PyCharm then the prompt could be handling the images in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moderate-sized trees, the `.svg` rendering *should* be a good option to produce vector graphic outputs.

Here's a minimal example showing the original figure and a zoomed-in portion at the bottom right:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=40).fit(X, y)
plt.figure()
plot_tree(clf, filled=True)
plt.savefig('testfig.svg', format='svg')
```

[image: A scikit-learn decision tree with 40 leaves. The bottom right-corner shows a zoomed in set of leaves with visible labels.]

---

Alternatively, if you have a copy of `graphviz` available, you can export the tree as a graphviz string and render the tree separately.

```py
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
with open("testdot.dot", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(export_graphviz(clf, filled=True))

# dot -Tpng testdot.dot -o testdot.png
```

[image]